# How to prevent a box with overflow-y: scroll from stealing the focus on tab on Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, accessibility, tabbing

Consider a page with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            .steal-focus { overflow-y: scroll }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/">
            <input type="text" value="First">
            <div class="steal-focus">Content</div>
            <input type="text" value="Second">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. Load this page on Firefox.
2. Hit tab a first time: the focus goes to the first text field.
3. Hit tab a second time: the focus goes to the `<div>` instead of the second text field, because of the `overflow-y: scroll`.

This behavior is unique to Firefox: this doesn't happen on IE, Safari, or Chrome. How can I get around this behavior, which sounds like a Firefox bug to me? I'd like the tab to skip over the `<div>` even if it has an `overflow-y: scroll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `tabIndex` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) to control the order of items that <kbd>Tab</kbd> jumps through. Like this:

```
<body>
    <form action="/">
        <input type="text" value="First" tabIndex="1">
        <div class="steal-focus">Content</div>
        <input type="text" value="Second" tabIndex="2">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Specifically, this means adding `tabindex="-1"` on the `<div>`. This works, thank you. Ideally, I'd like a solution in CSS, to counter-balance the `overflow-y: scroll`, so I don't have to change the generate markup.

Comment: @animuson: from the W3C document I linked: "This value must be a number between 0 and 32767" - why does it need to start at 1?

Comment: @Alessandro - personally, I would avoid using a `tabIndex` that's outside the range. But if it works, it works...

Comment: @Bears will eat you: If you read the rest of the documentation, setting it to 0 results in it being used in the order it appears in the document, so it will go to First (0), then Content (also 0), then Second (1). If it's 1 and 2, it will go First (1), Second (2), then Content (0). Everything defaults to 0, the order in which they appear. I tested both examples and 0, 0, 1 acts just like 0, 0, 0, but 1, 0, 2 will skip the division in the middle.

Comment: @Bears @animuson 0 is a special value in HTML5, so I would start with 1. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex

Comment: @Bears will eat you: -1 isn't outside range, but a way to tell the browser that this control shouldn't be able to get the focus. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex

Comment: As a side-note, I was hoping to be able to use `-moz-user-focus: ignore` in CSS, instead of adding `tabindex="-1"` to the markup, but failed to make this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671169/how-to-get-moz-user-focus-ignore-to-work

Comment: Yup, you guys are definitely right about the 0 and -1 values. Is it just me, or are those statements in W3C HTML4 docs contradictory?... at any rate, I tweaked my answer.

Comment: -moz-user-focus: ignore doesn't seem to actually work right in Firefox (bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=379939). So using the taxindex attribute is indeed the way to go.