# How to get -moz-user-focus: ignore to work?

Tags: firefox, tabbing

My understanding is that when using `-moz-user-focus: ignore` ([see doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-focus)) on an element, Firefox should skip that element when tabbing. However, try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/">
            <input type="text" value="First">
            <input type="text" value="Second" style="-moz-user-focus: ignore">
            <input type="text" value="Third">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

1. Hit tab a first time: you're on the first text field.
2. Hit tab a second time: you're on the second text field, despite the `-moz-user-focus: ignore`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a [bug covering this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=379939) in the Mozilla bug base. Until this bug is fixed, we can use `tabindex="-1"` instead of CSS as a workaround.